# Nexus 7 speed will not go into 6. and 7. gear

Tags: shimano, internally-geared-hub

Hope someone can help 
I have an elder Nexus 7 speed internal gear, which will not shift to 6. and 7. gear but go backwards. Instead of getting the 6. and 7. gear, I get 4. or 3. gear. The clickshifter is new and the cable runs smooth in the sleeve, and the gear is well adjusted acc. to the manual. I have had the gear out of the hub and it is well oiled and greased, and I've found no sticking parts or that kind at all. So it is really mysterious! Has someone amongst you experienced the same peculiarity and can you tell how to cure this?
Best regards
Tom

Comment: Just to make sure, the two red marks on the hub line up when you select the 4th gear?

Comment: Are/were there any metal fragments in the housing ?  I wonder if a spring has disintegrated.

Comment: Thanks for proposals Yes, the marks line up and as far as I could see there were no metal fragments in the housing. The idea of a defect spring sounds appealing though, so maybe I should dismantle the hub again....

Comment: What's the approximate mileage on the hub?  When was its last oil change ?

Answer (score 1):

have you checked that your shifter cables is in any way rusted or damaged? I had the same problem and i just got a new cable which fixed it quite nicely

Comment: Good point, but question says "shifter is new and the cable runs smooth in the sleeve"  so while this is something to check, OP has done that.

Comment: Yes, indeed a good point, but I am quite sure, that the cable is all right! I'll check again later this week. Thanks for the comments!